# Wifi adapter suddenly disappeared in Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

First of all, I'm not an experienced user so please be as clear as possible in all answers. I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a new HP Victus laptop ([This one](https://support.hp.com/ro-en/document/c07988984) except with Intel Core i7-12700H and GeForce RTX 3050 Ti). The wifi was working fine. I was not messing with any settings, it just suddenly disconnected and now it says "no wifi adapter found" in settings. I have already tried some solutions from similar questions but nothing works. I'm now online using a tethered android phone.

The wifi adapter does not show up using 'sudo lshw -C network':

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 16
       serial: a8:b1:3b:92:0a:eb
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-32-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:82204000-82204fff memory:82200000-82203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 12
       bus info: usb@3:3
       logical name: enx1e31043ced9f
       serial: 1e:31:04:3c:ed:9f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.19.0-32-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.16.27 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

I ran a wireless-info script i found. The output is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GsVbpR976w/).

`sudo dmesg | grep iwl` gives:

```
[    1.482435] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    1.482436] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:10878:f4df8641
```

`rfkill list` gives:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`iwconfig` gives:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

enx1e31043ced9f  no wireless extensions.
```

I hope I haven't messed things up even further trying things from other questions without knowing exactly what I was doing (there are so many, i've lost track of everything I've done). I will use this computer for studying and I've spent a lot of time setting up all the software I will need, CUDA for  molecular dynamics simulations and onedrive etc. So I would really like to avoid a fresh install if possible. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you asking about a USB wireless adapter?

Comment: No, the default one from the laptop

Comment: It is not seen in `lspci`. Maybe it is broken or disabled in BIOS. But just in case try to boot with a previous kernel using grub. If it is a dual-boot, then disable Fast Startup in Windows.

Comment: How can I do that? I googled it and it said to press shift+esc on startup but that does nothing?

Comment: It is ESC, not Shift + ESC.

Comment: I booted to the previous 5.15 kernel. That did not work

Comment: So, your device is broken, or disabled by a hardware switch, etc.

Comment: Christ. This is the second laptop I buy from amazon in a short time. First I got an Acer that I had to return because the keyboard had several keys not working and now this. Now I can either return it and get a new one or send it back to spain for a repair that takes 20 days. FML

Comment: What I find odd though is that according to [this](https://support.hp.com/ro-en/document/c07988984) the wifi adapter is a wifi bluetooth combo, and the bluetooth is working

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem. The WiFi disappeared in both Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11 (dual-boot). Fast boot was disabled in both Windows and BIOS. Bluetooth was working, but not WiFi.

I found a workaround:

1. When powering on the laptop, keep pressing DEL key to enter BIOS.
2. Change a setting that doesn't matter much, e.g. enable networking stack in UEFI.
3. In BIOS, save changes and reset.
4. After that, Ubuntu boots with WiFi on, and detects the adapter.

My laptop is different - it's MSI Titan gt77hx 13vi. Probably the WiFi or other hardware in it has the same issue.

The issue started to happen after something like this:

1. Hybrid sleep
2. Forcing shutdown with the power key when Ubuntu freezes when rebooting

Comment: I had exactly this problem on a Dell Precision, Ubuntu crashed during attempt to sleep, then I forced shutdown with the power key. Workaround also worked, thank you.

Comment: Using an older kernel (5.15.0-19) solved this issue for me. Dell Latitude 5420 i5 11th gen