# Realtek driver breaks on brand new Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, realtek, rtl

When I manage to install Ubuntu in its 22.04 (in a HP OMEN computer), everything is perfect until I enter Ubuntu Software to get everything up to date. Afterward, happens that I check my network card (MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter) with `lspci` command and `iwconfig` as well, and it disappears. I am almost sure that this happens when updating things in Ubuntu Software. After this the WiFi always stops working, and I have to reinstall Ubuntu again. I'll attach a screenshot with the three updates in "Ubuntu software" I think that could lead to the issue:

[image: screenshot]

I also was searching for the problem at first. No forums on the internet could help me to solve it, and I can see a lot of people complaining about this. I hope I could shed light on the issue.

Comment: I don't see how the *snap* packages are related; gnome-3-38-2004 is a theming package used by `firefox` & other snaps, snapd-desktop-integration involves packaging & core20 is a base system for running snap packages; none relate to networking or the linux kernel (thus kernel modules which are what *drivers* are). Did you install with 22.04.2 media?  was it recent? as there have been many other upgraded packages than those since the media was created.

Comment: @guiverc Hi! Actually I think you are right, non of these packages seem to be related to networking. I don't know what do you mean by media, and yes, it was yesterday evening, and again this morning. By the way, I have to make a correction about the network card. I said I have RTL8111/8168/8411 in my computer, but that's the Ethernet controller (the only one I could see when my network card was not detected), and now that I can detect everything, I checked I have MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter, in a HP OMEN computer.

Comment: @guiverc Done! Thank you, I didn't realize those things I had to do. I have used 22.04.2 LTS ISO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455967/wifi-adapter-suddenly-disappeared-in-ubuntu-22-04-02-lts) with the same issue, the same label (HP). What worked for me was the thing explained in one response of the post, which is rebooting from BIOS, making one change, saving, and exiting, and then the WiFi card is detected again.